# How to enable CSRF token with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, csrf

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.1. I think [CSRF protection is enabled by default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.10.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf) for this version of Spring Boot (correct me if I'm wrong). I am trying to set up CSRF protection for my java web application, but I'm not exactly sure what changes I need to make in order for the CSRF token to show up.

I am trying to check for the CSRF token via the browser. However, it seems the name and value of the token is showing up as blank.

My jsp code:

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${model.containerObjects}" var="file">
        <tr>
            <form action="/path/container?fileName=${file.getName()}" method="post" id="${file.getName()}">
                <input form="${file.getName()}" type="hidden" value="${file.getName()}" />
                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                <td><a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('${file.getName()}').submit()">${file.getName()}</a></td>
                <td>${file.getContentLength()}</td>
                <td>${file.getLastModified()}</td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

However, the line where (I assume) the CSRF token should be on the front end looks like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="" value="">
```

I've also made sure the backend method corresponding to this endpoint is annotated with @POST. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: yes, csrf should be enabled by default. Is the spring-security dependency available at runtime (did you add it to the `pom.xml` or gradle file?)? Or is it possible that you somehow disabled it (e.g. via a custom `@Configuration` class?)?

Comment: @qutax Thanks, I haven't confirmed yet, but that sounds like the issue (I did not add the spring security dependency to my pom.xml).

Comment: @qutax That was indeed the missing piece. Thanks again!

Comment: glad to hear it! I've added it as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61505985/10551549 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we found out via a conversation in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61488299/how-to-enable-csrf-token-with-spring-boot?noredirect=1#comment108781456_61488299) of the question, the OP did not add the necessary spring-security dependency, which is required for the CSRF protection (as it is a feature of Spring Security).

Answer (score 1):

You should add it manually, if you want to see it in the html source code. Something like this:

`<meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>`

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding (I don't have a strong grasp of this), but I tried adding it manually with the line 

<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

And it is that line that is showing up as blank when I inspect the html source code. I followed the instructions here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.10.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-include-csrf-token

Comment: @Azianese oh that's my bad, I though you were using thymeleaf. By the looks of it you did everything right, might be something wrong in the config, I suggest you a request to your controller from insomnia or postman to see if csrf is actually on, those request should have a 403 (I think) without the csrf token

Comment: Turns out I was missing the spring-security dependency in my Pom.xml. Thanks for your input anyways :)